# A system.net.webException when using httpclient on xamarin android

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

error: NameResolutionFailure

```
public class JsonConverter
{       
    public async Task<string> GetStringbyJson(string link)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient ();
        HttpResponseMessage message = await client.GetAsync (link);
        return await message.Content.ReadAsStringAsync ();

    }
}

public async override void OnActivityCreated (Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    base.OnActivityCreated (savedInstanceState);

    lst = View.FindViewById<ListView> (Resource.Id.lstHome);

    var result = await json.GetStringbyJson ("https://api-v2.soundcloud.com/explore/Popular+Music?tag=out-of-experiment&limit=30&linked_partitioning=1&client_id=9ac2b330e1b3&offset="+offset);
}
```

App just run when I removed "var result". I test app on device

Comment: What I get to see is there are two issues,
1. Check for all the permissions(INTERNET_PERMISSION)
2. If on a device /// check if wifi or mobile data is up and running properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is exactly what it says - it is unable to resolve the domain name you've given it.

The most likely cause is neglecting to enable INTERNET_PERMISSION in the app's manifest.  But it could also be a general networking issue on the device.  Can you resolve the domain from the device's browser?